# Disable Auto formatting of date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Am having issue where if someone enters an invalid date manually such as "%/4/12" into the datepicker it will autoformat it to "04/12/2017" or if you enter "12/123/20258" it formats to ‘12/12/2025 which I don't want. Is there any way to disable this? Here is what I already have:

```
$(function () {
        $('#new-effective-date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            defaultDate: false,
            useCurrent: false,
            keepInvalid: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could make the datepicker textbox readonly which would prevent manual data entry.

Comment: you are telling it to keep invalid entries

Comment: @charlietfl it does keep invalid text but if you enter "%/4/12" it will auto format for some reason to "04/12/2017" or if you enter "12/123/20258" it formats to ‘12/12/2025

Comment: @akerra I can't do that, it wouldn't be accessible for people with only keyboards.

Comment: seems like you will need to override the $('#new-effective-date').change() event, do a preventDefault(), and implement some custom logic to format the input (or discard it).

Comment: @akerra thats the questions then, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

**useStrict**

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usestrict

and Change your codes to this:

```
$(function () {
        $('#new-effective-date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            useStrict: true,
        keepInvalid: true,
        });
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, it still lets me enter  "12/123/20258" and it will  auto format to ‘12/12/2025.

Comment: Guess you can look deep in your codes, the answer I gave has completely solve the same question for me.